# How to start hyperledger fabric network with project name reln and channel name relianceorgs

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have passed following commands :

`mkdir workspace 
cd  workspace`

`git clone https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples.git`

`cd fabric-samples`

`./scripts/bootstrap.sh 1.4.1 1.4.1 0.4.14`

`cd reliance-network`

What command to be next for project name reln & channel name relianceorgs ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to modify configtx.yaml and crypto-config.yaml for channel name as well as organisation name, configtx.yaml will be used to generate genesis block and channel.tx file, while crypto-config.yaml file will be used to generate crypto material such as tls files and msp (i.e membership service provider) for organization. you can use first-network or basic network in fabric sample as an example. it would be better if you go through Read the docs https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/build_network.html you will find all the commands and instructions that you need to follow.